# MVC View syntax <% Model.CurrentModel ?? "All Models" %> as Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Setting a page title I have the following MVC View Syntax

```
<title> Category : <% Model.CurrentModel ?? "All Models" %></title>
```

Which writes "Category : All Models" to a page title if `Model.CurrentModel` is null.

I've tried to use the same with Razor View engine, but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@(Model.CurrentModel ?? "All Models")
```

Try that.